# phpunit in mvc structure

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phpunit

i have just installed phpunit on my ubuntu.

now i wan't to implement some tests into my (php code) mvc structur. but i don't have any clue where i get the output of the test ...

i have controller function which looks like this:

```
public function run_test(){
        error_log("i was called correctly");
        $mytest = new modeltest();
        $mytest->run();

        // $this->outputvar = testresults ??

        $this->set_template("mytestview");
    }
```

as well as my testmodel:

```
class ModelTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

    public function testWorks(){
        error_log("i was called correctly as well");
        $model = new model();
        $this->assertEquals(3, $model->works(2, 1));
    }

}
```

works is just a simple function for testing phpunit running, which adds two values.

how do i get the results of the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THat's not how you're supposed to run PHPUnit's tests. See [chapter 5 in PHPUnit manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html)

In other words, testing process should be separated from your application (so you do not need your own controller for that). A command line `phpunit` tool does all the dirty job for you. NetBeans IDE (and maybe others) also allow you to run this tool from within the IDE.

Comment: aaah ... now i got it :-) i used it last time when it was 2004 or 2005.. many things where different those days.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and assume you're using the latest version of PHPUnit and are running it from the command line. If you want the output of the test, the test runner offers a few choices for storing output:

```
--log-graphviz <file>  Log test execution in GraphViz markup.
--log-json <file>      Log test execution in JSON format.
--log-tap <file>       Log test execution in TAP format to file.
--log-xml <file>       Log test execution in XML format to file.
```

These are from the PHPUnit docs. If you just specify a file name it will store the output within the directory you're running the tests from.

Answer (score 1):

Quick install on Ubunutu (just in case)

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear

sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

then go to the folder where your test is:

```
phpunit ourTest.php
```

and @Mchl linked you to the documentation